# Load list of selected language fail

Tags: c#, jquery, sharepoint-2013

My original code is this one:

```
function MenuPopulate(url, listname, target) {
    var lang = "Espanol";
    if ((window.location.href.indexOf("lang=en") > 0)) {
        lang = "English"; 
}

function failureMenu(data, target) {
    console.log(data);
    $(target).text("Ocurrió un error en la carga del menú. Por favor revise la consola para más información");
}

    }
    // Getting our list items
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?$select=Title,Enlace&$orderby=Posicion&$top=6&$filter=Idioma eq '" + lang + "'",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            completeMenu(data, target);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failureMenu(data, target);
        }
    });
}

function completeMenu(data, target) {
    var prefix = "<ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>";
    var sufix = "</ul>";
    var items = data.d.results;
    var menu = "";
    for (item in items) {
    if(items[item].Title == "ÚNETE A NOSOTROS"  ){
    /*menu += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-link' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mymodal'>"*/
   menu += "<li><a href='#mymodal' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mymodal'>" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>"
    }
    else if(items[item].Title == "CONTÁCTANOS"){
    menu += "<li><a href='#mymodal2' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mymodal2'>" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>"
    }
    else if(items[item].Title == "JOIN TO US"){
     menu += "<li><a href='#mymodal' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mymodal'>" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>"
    }
    else if(items[item].Title == "CONTACT"){
      menu += "<li><a href='#mymodal2' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mymodal2'>" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>"
    }   

    else{
        menu += "<li><a href=" + items[item].Enlace + ">" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>";
    }
    }
    $(target).html(prefix + menu + sufix);
}

function failureMenu(data, target) {
    console.log(data);
    $(target).text("Ocurrió un error en la carga del menú. Por favor revise la consola para más información");
}
```

It works perfectly, but now I want to change code to open different modal depending of language selected:
So there I change `mymodal` to `mymodal3`, and `mymodal2` to `mymodal4`

```
 else if(items[item].Title == "JOIN TO US"){
         menu += "<li><a href='#mymodal3' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mymodal3'>" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>"
        }
        else if(items[item].Title == "CONTACT"){
          menu += "<li><a href='#mymodal4' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mymodal4'>" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>"
        }
```

So In my function:

```
if ((window.location.href.indexOf("lang=en") > 0)) {
    lang = "English"; 

 }
```

I get code of english modal and put into it, like these:

```
function MenuPopulate(url, listname, target) {
    var lang = "Espanol";
    if ((window.location.href.indexOf("lang=en") > 0)) {
        lang = "English"; 

    function completeMenu(data, target) {
    var prefix = "<ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>";
    var sufix = "</ul>";
    var items = data.d.results;
    var menu = "";
    for (item in items) {
    if(items[item].Title == "JOIN TO US"){

     menu += "<li><a href='#mymodal3' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mymodal3'>" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>"    }
    else if(items[item].Title == "CONTACT"){
     menu += "<li><a href='#mymodal4' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mymodal4'>" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>"
    }    
    else{
        menu += "<li><a href=" + items[item].Enlace + ">" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>";
    }
    }
    $(target).html(prefix + menu + sufix);
}

function failureMenu(data, target) {
    console.log(data);
    $(target).text("Ocurrió un error en la carga del menú. Por favor revise la consola para más información");
}

    }
    // Getting our list items
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?$select=Title,Enlace&$orderby=Posicion&$top=6&$filter=Idioma eq '" + lang + "'",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            completeMenu(data, target);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failureMenu(data, target);
        }
    });
}

function completeMenu(data, target) {
    var prefix = "<ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>";
    var sufix = "</ul>";
    var items = data.d.results;
    var menu = "";
    for (item in items) {
    if(items[item].Title == "ÚNETE A NOSOTROS"  ){
    /*menu += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-link' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mymodal'>"*/
   menu += "<li><a href='#mymodal' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mymodal'>" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>"
    }
    else if(items[item].Title == "CONTÁCTANOS"){
    menu += "<li><a href='#mymodal2' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#mymodal2'>" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>"
    }
    else{
        menu += "<li><a href=" + items[item].Enlace + ">" + items[item].Title + "</a></li><li class='divider-vertical'></li>";
    }
    }
    $(target).html(prefix + menu + sufix);
}

function failureMenu(data, target) {
    console.log(data);
    $(target).text("Ocurrió un error en la carga del menú. Por favor revise la consola para más información");
}
```

And it works great for english version (`mymodal3 and mymodal4`) but in spanish version list doesn´t populate, it just don´t pass to my second   `function completeMenu(data, target) {`

I really appreciate Help. Regards